# Trouble setting up instance to host a static site on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using a Mac book pro. Only the private IP is showing up...
I tried to upload the public key but not able to up load...

I need help...the steps to to set up instance, connect ssh, install WordPress

Tried everything...just frustrated

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "host a static site"? WordPress is not 'static' in that it runs PHP and generates the pages when they are requested. If your site is truely static, you could host it on Amazon S3 without needing an Amazon EC2 instance. If you are wanting to use WordPress, then Amazon Lightsail offers a 'click and deploy' solution and its pricing includes an amount of Data Transfer that will make things cheaper for you.

Answer (score 0):

hmm..., there is a pretty easy Getting Started with EC2 on the official AWS page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html

on top of that, there is also a nice page to setting up Wordpress on that instance: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html